# What executable format normally results in smaller file sizes?

Tags: executable-format

What executable format normally results in smaller file sizes? For example, I've heard the a.out format is smaller than ELF's. This question is cross platform, so MS-DOS too.

Comment: Why do you ask? The overhead is small.

Comment: Your question is absurd on several levels.  "Extension" != "format".  An "a.out" file typically *is* in ELF format.  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions and formats are unrelated.
a.out is normally ELF format on linux systems, while it will be some other formats in BSDs; ".out" is just the default extension, unrelated to the format.

Aside from the format, the original language will also make the binary file vary in size, as well as the compilation flags used.

Answer (score 0):

My smallest PE file produced with an hex editor is about 380 bytes and is able to store any ressources I like. (Well with ressources it's bigger)

Answer (score 0):

You are right: ELF carries more information than the old (deprecated under Linux?) "a.out" format. But the "overhead" (actually, quite useful metadata) is small for any  Desktop application.

**For MS-DOS**, COM files are smaller (and more restricted) than EXEs.

Comment: The "old" format you're referring to was Unix/SVR3 "COFF".  It's long since been supplanted by ELF (and ELF-64).  Just like DOS .exe's used to be OMF, later COFF, then Windows "PE".  And like Linux "a.out/ELF", a Microsoft .exe can be any of OMF, COFF, PE.  There is *NOT* a 1::1 correspondence between "file suffix" and "file format"!

Comment: PS: One of the reasons DOS .COM files could be so much smaller than .EXE's is that .COM required fixed Code and Data segments.  So pointers could be shorter.  And the code more compact.  That is *not* an issue in 32-bit programs, where addresses are *linear*, segments aren't *used* ... and pointers are never wider or narrower than 32-bits.